# Asterisk load chan_mobile returns no mobile phones on search

Tags: asterisk

I am reading through [this](http://wiki.stocksy.co.uk/wiki/Asterisk_1.8_with_chan_mobile_on_CentOS_6) to configure my mobile to asterisk via bluetooth.

```
sudo hcitool dev
Devices:
hci0    00:1B:10:00:2A:EC

sudo ./simple-agent.py hci0 78:9E:D0:3D:55:38
Creating device failed: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists: Already Exists
```

chan-mobile contents are

```
[general]
interval=30
[adapter]
id=hci0
address=00:1B:10:00:2A:EC
context=incoming-mobile
```

Now, when I load the mobile `asterisk> module load chan_mobile` it loads, but nothing is returned on `mobile search`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, I did not configure the chan_mobile completely. I missed out the phone part.

```
[sidphone]
address=78:9E:D0:3D:55:38
port=1
context=incoming-mobile
adapter=hci0
```